# How to prove two groups are isomorphic?

Tags: group-theory

> Let $G$ be the group $\{1,-1\}$ and let $H$ be the group $\{z,-z, \bar z, -\bar z\}$ of isometries of $\mathbb C$. Show that $H$ is isomorphic to $G \times G$.

My attempt:

$G \times G =\{(1,1),(1,-1),(-1,1),(-1,-1)\}$

So in order to prove isomorphism I need to find a linear bijection $\theta$ that can map elements in $H$ to elements in $G \times G$

How to find such a function provided we do not know $z$?

Comment: First show that $G\times G$ is isomorphic, then show that $H$ is isomorphic... :-) (This is a callback to [this story](http://mathoverflow.net/a/53905/7206)...)

Comment: @AsafKaragila What do you mean by saying a set is isomorphic? My understanding is that it must be isomorphic to some other sets...

Comment: You need to find a bijection that respects the group operation

Comment: How is the group operation of $H$ defined? In this simple case there should be an obvious choice for $\theta$ (there are not very many order 4 groups...)

Comment: @SamWeatherhog Yes this is what I am thinking. But I find it difficult to obtain such bijection. Could you provide an example?

Comment: "[G]roup […] of isometries of $\mathbb{C}$", that means you look at the four functions $\operatorname{id} \colon z \mapsto z$, $\sigma \colon z \mapsto \overline{z}$, $\nu \colon z \mapsto -z$ and $\pi \colon z \mapsto - \overline{z}$. The group operation is composition of maps.

Comment: It should be easy because there are only four elements. The identity in $G\times G$ must map to the identity in $H$. Then probably $-z\mapsto (1,-1)$, $\bar{z}\mapsto (-1,1)$ will work. Or maybe the other way around.

Comment: How to should I define the map in a formal way? I am a self-learner, so I am not familiar with formal staff. Could someone provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your confusion comes from the way you have written $H$. Since $H$ is a group of transformations, let's rewrite it as:
$$H = \{I,X,Y,XY\}$$
where these transformations are defined as follows:
$$I:z\rightarrow z$$
$$X:z\rightarrow -z$$
$$Y:z\rightarrow \bar{z}$$
$$XY=YX:z\rightarrow -\bar{z}$$

Perhaps the simplest way to prove the isomorphism is to show that the group multiplication tables are equal.

Another way would be to give an explicit isomorphism $\varphi$.

Obviously, we should have $\varphi((1,1))=I$. Noticing that $$(1,-1)\times(-1,1)=(-1,-1),$$ we can choose $\varphi((1,-1)) = X$ and $\varphi((-1,1))=Y$ and we know that the multiplication rule will carry over.